# How can I tell what the past participle of a word is?

Tags: tense, verbs, past-participles, participles

How can I tell what the past participle of something is- especially if the past participle is usually different?
Ex: Drink = have drunk, choose = had chosen, and bring = have brought. If these are all past participles, how can I know how to figure out the past participles of other words?

Comment: This is the kind of information you can easily find in any decent English textbook. But as a short answer to your question, here's what you need to know: past participles of irregular verbs should be learned by heart and past participles of regular verbs are formed by adding an *ed* to the end of a verb. That's how it's basically done.

Comment: Thanks! I needed to know how to figure this out for one of my English projects. This helped with how to find the information. I only have one question- where would the past participle be in a dictionary?

Comment: @bnicoleo0202 Note that a lot of verbs are built by adding a prefix or such to an existing verb, which usually means they'll retain the base verb's forms. [This list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_irregular_verbs) might come in handy. For instance, *sit – sat – sat*, then *babysit – babysat – babysat*, etc. That'll eliminate a good deal of inflectional forms (more accurately, *shapes*) you have to learn. Moreover, verbed forms are normally regular, so you don't have to worry about those. E.g., the noun *Google*, when verbed, has the preterit and past participle forms *googled*.

Comment: Collins and M-W list the 'principle parts' immediately after the headword. Oxford Online, oddly, does not; but you can look at the many example sentences and find a perfect or passive that will provide you the past/passive participle.

Comment: Learner's dictionaries usually list them. See, for instance, the [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/babysit?q=babysit), which has a little expandable box titled Verb Forms right under the pronunciation guide. The [LDOCE](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/babysit) lists them right at the beginning of the entry in the parentheses (if the verb has irregular forms to begin with).

Comment: Thank you for the online dictionary links, as well as the information :D :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambridge Dictionary gives the participle under the verb definition, if it is irregular. The verb "dig" is irregular, and the participle, "dug" is shown. By contrast, "look" is a regular verb and so no participle is shown, indicating that you form the participle in the normal way. Oxford does not do this in its verb definitions, but has a handy page summarising the formation of regular verb present and past tenses and participles, and a list of common irregular verbs.

[Regular and irregular verbs (Oxford)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/regular-and-irregular-verbs)

[image]
[image]

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dig)